# How to refresh the TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have the following situation:

[image]

I have activity and several fragments. At the beginning of the onCreate method I always load the fragment present in the picture above:

```
  private void setInitialFragment() {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        DietDiaryFragment dietDiaryFragment = (DietDiaryFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("DietDiaryFragment");

        if (dietDiaryFragment == null) {

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            dietDiaryFragment = new DietDiaryFragment();
            setArguments(dietDiaryFragment);

            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_main_screen, dietDiaryFragment,"DietDiaryFragment");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Where the setArguments method is as follows:

```
private void setArguments(DietDiaryFragment dietDiaryFragment) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putParcelable("breakfast", breakfast);
    bundle.putParcelable("lunch", lunch);
    bundle.putParcelable("dinner", dinner);
    bundle.putParcelable("snacks", snacks);

    dietDiaryFragment.setArguments(bundle);

}
```

In activity, I download from Firebase all products from a given meal, depending on the date 
and send it to the fragment where I showed above:

```
private void getProductsFromDatabaseLunch() {

        lunch.getTotalProducts().clear();
        lunch.getIdProducts().clear();
        lunch.setTotalCalories(0);

        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(currentUserUID)
                .collection("Types of Meals").document("Lunch")
                .collection("Date of Lunch").document(date)
                .collection("List of Products")
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                    for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: task.getResult().getDocuments()) {

                        lunch.getIdProducts().add(documentSnapshot.getId());
                        lunch.getTotalProducts().add(documentSnapshot.toObject(Product.class));
                    }

                    lunch.calculateTotalCalories();
                    onSendTotalCaloriesLunch.sendTotalCaloriesLunch(lunch.getTotalCalories());
                }

                if(getFragmentRefreshLunchAdapter() != null) {

                    getFragmentRefreshLunchAdapter().refreshLunchAdapter();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Downloading products from Firebase is asynchronous, so first empty ArrayLists without products will be passed, only after a while products are added. Displaying products in RecyclerView is no problem because I refresh the Adapter using interfaces.

```
if(getFragmentRefreshLunchAdapter() != null) {

   fragmentRefreshLunchAdapter.refreshLunchAdapter();
}
```

But...  What about the rest? For example, in the drawing I marked TextView responsible for the total calories of a given meal. Here it will always be zero, because if there are no products at the beginning nothing can be calculated. 
I solved this problem using interfaces:

```
onSendTotalCaloriesDinner.sendTotalCaloriesDinner(dinner.getTotalCalories());
```

Where method is as follows:

```
 ((MainScreen)getActivity()).onSetSendTotalCaloriesLunch(new MainScreen.OnSendTotalCaloriesLunch() {
            @Override
            public void sendTotalCaloriesLunch(float calories) {

                if(lunch.getTotalProducts().size() == 0) {

                    textViewTotalCaloriesLunch.setText("");

                } else {

                    textViewTotalCaloriesLunch.setText(product.formatNumberWithoutDecimalPlaces(calories));                }
            }
        });
```

Is there any other way to solve this problem? Will I have to send all values ​​individually via interfaces? The problem also appears when I try to navigate between fragments using BottomNavigationView, then zero also comes out. What, e.g. if I want to create a diagram, will I also have to build it through the interface? 
Is there any elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you attach an onChange listener to your arrayList, so that way whenever you firebase returns values, it will trigger onChange in your arrayList and you can change your textView from there:

```
theList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Item>() {
     public void onChanged(Change<tem> c) {

         }
     });
```